# Dynamo db limit on secondary indexes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

For my application , I would need different types of indexes.  Dynamo db is best suited for my case. The only disadvantage, however, is the number of indexes supported . Is there any alternative or work around for this ?

Comment: Can you share some of your use cases so I can better understand why you need so many indexes? Usually a key-value store is not the best option when you have such requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You could enable a [DynamoDB Stream](http://dynamodb-preview.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/docs/streams-dg/About.html) on your base table, and use the [cross-region replication library](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-cross-region-library) to keep a copy of your table up to date. The replica could even be in the same region. You can have different indexes on your base table than you do on the read-only replica. This way, you could effectively have more GSI than you would normally be able to have on one table.